# Create a dataframe from a list of tables in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dataframe that I need to populate from a list in R. The list contains 2003 tables representing land cover data for different counties. Each table has two rows - the column labels and the row of land cover data. Unfortunately, each table has a different number of columns (if for that county the landcover class was not present instead of getting a zero it dropped the column when the list was created).

What I want is a dataframe that is 2003 rows long and 15 columns wide (one column for each land cover class).

When I tried 
`df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(l), nrow=132, byrow=T))`
based on another question, it created a long table of two columns (one with labels for all 2003 counties and the values in the second column). Because each table had unequal lengths I can't convert that to the wide format.

some sample data:

```
l <- replicate(
     2003,
     list(sample(1:100, sample(1:15,15))),
     simplify = FALSE
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

If your object is actually a list of data frames, you should be able to do `data.table::rbindlist(your_list, fill = T)`. Since your example isn't actually a list of data frames, an extra step is needed.

```
library(data.table)

l <- lapply(l, function(x){
  x <- as.list(x[[1]])
  setNames(x, paste0('V', seq_along(x)))})

df <- rbindlist(l, fill = T)
```

In base R

```
# make the lengths all the same
l <- lapply(l, function(x) c(x[[1]], rep(NA, max(0, 15 - length(x[[1]])))))

# rbind and convert to df
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, l))

dim(df)
# [1] 2003   15
```